# Issue while running MongoDB on Mac - DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead

Tags: database, mongodb, backend

I m trying to run locally installed MongoDB(community edition7.0)on mac, while I m starting mongo using "`mongosh`" or "`mongo`" below is the error I m getting

`(node:28156) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The` punycode`module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead. (Use`node --trace-deprecation ... `to show where the warning was created) MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

```
node --version
v21.2.0
  
Build Info: {
"version": "7.0.2",
"gitVersion": "02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a",
"modules": [],
"allocator": "system",
"environment": {
    "distarch": "aarch64",
    "target_arch": "aarch64"
}
```

Comment: Is this resolved? I face the same issue.

Comment: @Manoj Nope this is not resolved yet for me.

Comment: Oh okay. I am connecting with the Mongo support team. They're trying to locate the reason. If resolved I'll update here.

Comment: @Manoj  any update on this issue, I am also getting the same issue,

Comment: No still same problem. I contacted Mongo support using their chat support and got and a custom alternative URL. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

First start mongodb as a background process like;

for intel processors:

mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork

for silicon processors:

mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork

then try to use mongosh in terminal, you are gonna still get the same error but will able to use mongosh.

Comment: Tried with above commands to run in background in Sillicon processor here is the result. This is what I see,                                                                                      "mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 83233 ERROR: child process failed, exited with 1
To see additional info"                 mongosh is trowing the same error mentioned above and not able to get into the mongodb shell to access the databases since it is failing to connect.

Comment: i also get the same error when i start the server like that. but after getting that error try to write the "mongosh" command. if you see something like "test" in terminal then try to write "show dbs" command. if it is works then go on like that for now. :)

Comment: Sorry , for me it's not happening. I Mongo is never starting for me for the command "mongosh" and throws (node:85166) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead. Any hnt would be much appritiated.